# Storing objects on a Process?

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing, python-multithreading

I would like to store an object on a subclass of `multiprocessing.Process` as follows:

```
class TestProcess( Process ):
    def __init__( self, foo ):
        super( TestProcess, self ).__init__()
        self.foo = foo
    def run( self ):
        from time import sleep
        sleep( 3 )
        self.bar = self.foo

p = TestProcess( 5 )
p.start()
p.join()
print( p.bar ) # raises AttributeError
```

This works fine when `Process` is switched out with `Thread`, but I'm clearly missing something.  What?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `TestProcess.run()` is running in a child process, it assigns `self.bar` in the child process, which cannot effect parent process. 
The following code will show you the different:

```
import os
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue

class TestProcess( Process ):
    def __init__( self, foo ):
        super( TestProcess, self ).__init__()
        self.foo = foo
        self.bar = None
        self.que = Queue()
    def run( self ):
        from time import sleep
        sleep( 1 )
        self.bar = self.foo
        print( "pid2=%s, p.bar=%s" % (os.getpid(), self.bar ))
        self.que.put(self.bar)

p = TestProcess( 5 )
p.start()
p.join()
print( "pid1=%s, p.bar=%s" % (os.getpid(), p.bar ))
print(p.que.get())
```

You will see pid1 and pid2 are different. And, of course, if you use Thread, they run in same process, so it works.

If you do need store data in child process, then transfer to parent process, then involve inter-process-communication. You can use Queue.

Comment: This explains a lot, but it doesn't really show a way of accessing `p.bar`, as was the original intent.

Comment: Should work fine.  This...complicates my code a bit...

Also, in this case it would make more sense to use a `Pipe` since I'm only dealing with the one process.  I'll read into it more.

Thanks.

Comment: I should also add that the process above will never end since `Queue.put()` will wait until `Queue.get()` is run to finish execution.  `p.join()` will never finish in the way things are lain out above, but it's not really needed.

Answer (score 1):

When you switch from `threading` to `multiprocessing` and back, you're switching from an environment where every thread shares the same memory to one where nothing is shared unless explicitly shared. If you want to share variables between processes, you can use the `Value`, `Array`, one of the `Queue` classes, or another one of the shared constructs.

```
import os
from multiprocessing import Process, Value

class TestProcess( Process ):
    def __init__( self, foo ):
        super( TestProcess, self ).__init__()
        self.foo = foo
        self.bar = Value('i', 0)
    def run( self ):
        from time import sleep
        sleep( 1 )
        self.bar.value = self.foo
        print( "pid2=%s, p.bar=%s" % (os.getpid(), self.bar.value ))

p = TestProcess( 5 )
p.start()
p.join()
print( "pid1=%s, p.bar=%s" % (os.getpid(), p.bar.value ))
print(p.bar.value)
```

Comment: Could you provide an example for this case?

Comment: Sure, added. The types of values that can be stored in a `Value` are limited, while Queues and Pipes can hold anything that can be pickled (I think).

Comment: Is there any way to go beyond the pickleable?  `bar`, in this case, is actually a class instance.  I can make the class picklable (I think), but that muddies up the class definition quite a bit.